# Applescript to delete contacts from list

Tags: iphone, macos, applescript, contacts, automator

I accidentally added about 600 contacts to my Mac addressbook from a friend's iPhone I synced to my Mac a couple weeks ago. Unfortunately I dont have a backup of my contacts and now they are all synced with my iPhone and iCloud.
I was able to export all the unwanted contacts as ".vcf" files from my friends phone so I have about 600 files like "John Doe.vcf" and also a plain text list of just the contact names.

Ideally I would like a script that matches the data inside the VCF file to make sure I'm deleteing the right contact.

Idea #2 would be to delete the contacts that matches the name in list, skipping the searches that return two or more results (that way I dont lose my own contacts with same name as my friend's)

I started by attempint to delete a single contact using the following applescript but with no luck. Please help!

```
set daName to "John Doe"

tell application "Contacts"
    repeat with onePerson in people
        if (value of name of onePerson) is daName then
            delete onePerson
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

--UPDATE--

Here is the final code I used to perform the task. I added a loop at the top that cycles through the list of names copied in the clipboard. I also added the name of the duplicated contact in the dialog box so I could take note of it.

Tips:

- Make a backup of all your contacts before running the script.
- If you    want to see the number of contacts "magically" decreasing
  while    running the script, scroll down to the of your contacts in
  your    address book and you'll see the totla amount of contacts
  there.

FINAL CODE

```
set the clipboard to (the clipboard as text)
set the_strings to the clipboard

repeat with this_string in paragraphs of the_strings
    set daName to this_string
    DeleteContact(daName)
end repeat


on DeleteContact(theName)
    tell application "Contacts"
        set myList to every person whose name is theName
        set Nb to count of myList
        if Nb = 0 then return -- no record found
        if Nb > 1 then
            display dialog theName & " (too many found: do nothing)"
        else
            set myperson to item 1 of myList -- only 1 found to be deleted
            delete myperson
            save
        end if
    end tell
end DeleteContact
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script bellow contains sub-routine which check name and delete. I added some comments to make it easier to adapt for your need :you can build a loop looking for your card and calling the DeleteContact sub-routine.

```
set daName to "John Doe"
DeleteContact(daName)


on DeleteContact(theName)
tell application "Contacts"
    set myList to every person whose name is theName
    set Nb to count of myList
    if Nb = 0 then return -- no record found
    if Nb > 1 then
        display dialog "too many found: do nothing"
    else
        set myperson to item 1 of myList -- only 1 found to be deleted
        delete myperson
        save
    end if
end tell
end DeleteContact
```

In case same name exist in multiple contact, I display a dialog, but up to you to decide what to do here.

Comment: Thanks PBELL!! This solved my problem and saved me many hours of cleaning up my contacts manually. I made some small changes to the code, I'll post them to help someone else in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

Gio

This is a script I had and it may address your problem although you never said what the problem was.

```
tell application "Contacts"
  local results,dlist,dloop
  set results to {}
  set dlist to people whose (first name  contains "Oxnard" or (last name  is equal to "Abercrombe"))
  repeat with dloop in dlist
    delete dloop
  end repeat
  set end of results to "Records deleted :" & count of dlist
  save
return results
end tell
```

Note that the Contacts dictionary does define a `name` property however it will be based on preference settings.